# image placing does not work at first load

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

At first laod, image and the escape button do not appear in the designated place.
Go on and close the divs by clicking the escape button and then execute the function again.
Surprisingly, at the second execution, it works perfectly.
Does anyone know why results are different at the first load?

(FireFox)

`< html>
    < head>
        < style type="text/css">
            #wievbackground { 
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                background-color:red;
            }
            #escapebutton {
                position:fixed;
                background-color:white;
                height:40px;
                width:40px;
            }
        < /style>
    < /head>

        <body>

            <div id="wievwrap"> </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function itemview(itemurl) {
                    document.getElementById("wievwrap").innerHTML = ' <div id="wievbackground"> </div> ';
                    document.getElementById("wievbackground").innerHTML = ' <img id="theitem" style="position:fixed" src="' + itemurl + '"> ';
                    document.getElementById("wievbackground").innerHTML += '<div onclick="document.getElementById(\'wievwrap\').innerHTML=\'\';"  id="escapebutton"></div>';

                    document.getElementById("theitem").style.left = document.getElementById("theitem").parentElement.offsetWidth / 2 - document.getElementById("theitem").offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
                    document.getElementById("theitem").style.top = document.getElementById("theitem").parentElement.offsetHeight / 2 - document.getElementById("theitem").offsetHeight / 2 + "px";

                    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("theitem").style.left) + parseInt(document.getElementById("theitem").offsetWidth - document.getElementById("escapebutton").offsetWidth / 2);

                    document.getElementById("escapebutton").style.left = x + "px";
                    document.getElementById("escapebutton").style.top = parseInt(document.getElementById("theitem").style.top) - document.getElementById("escapebutton").offsetHeight / 2 + "px";

                }
            </script>
            <div></div>
            <div onclick="itemview('smt.png')">function</div>
        </body>
    </html>`

Comment: are you also using jquery? could you create a fiddle? probably the problem is that the function doesnt gets executed before the click.

Comment: this is the whole code. function should not get executed before click. Problem is "at the first click(run) of the function image goes to wrong place". when i terminate the divs by clicking the escape button and execute the function again, everything works perfectly.

Comment: ok, it's for sure a positioning problem. please create a fiddle --> http://www.jsfiddle.net and many people will help

Comment: It's this line: `document.getElementById("wievwrap").innerHTML = ' <div id="wievbackground"> </div> ';` wipes out your script. Also `#wievwrap`'s closing tag is missing.